# KafkaConsumer: how to increase log level?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I run my Java application and instantiate the KafkaConsumer object (fed with the minimum required properties: key and value deserializer and group_id); I see lots of INFO messages on the StdOut (If I provide unsupported properties, I also see WARNING messages).

I want to see when fetch events take place. I assume that by increasing the loglevel to DEBUG I will be able to see that. Unfortunately, I am not able to increase it.

I tried to feed the log4j.properties file in multiple ways (placing the file at specific paths and also passing it as parameter (-Dlog4j.configuration). The output remains the same.

```sh
cd /Users/user/git/kafka/toys; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath ch.demo.toys.CarthusianConsumer" -Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -DskipTests=true org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building toys 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ toys ---
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:00 PM org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig logAll
INFO: ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-server:9090, kafka-server:9091, kafka-server:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = carthusian-consumer
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 100000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = DEBUG
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo <init>
INFO: Kafka version: 2.3.0
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo <init>
INFO: Kafka commitId: fc1aaa116b661c8a
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo <init>
INFO: Kafka startTimeMs: 1562763121219
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer subscribe
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Subscribed to topic(s): sequence
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata update
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Cluster ID: REIXp5FySKGPHlRyfTALLQ
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$FindCoordinatorResponseHandler onSuccess
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Discovered group coordinator kafka-tds:9091 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator onJoinPrepare
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
Revoke event: []
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator sendJoinGroupRequest
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] (Re-)joining group
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator sendJoinGroupRequest
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] (Re-)joining group
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1 onSuccess
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Successfully joined group with generation 96
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator onJoinComplete
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Setting newly assigned partitions: sequence-1, sequence-0
Assignment event: [sequence-1, sequence-0]
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState lambda$requestOffsetReset$3
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition sequence-1
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState lambda$requestOffsetReset$3
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition sequence-0
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState maybeSeekUnvalidated
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Resetting offset for partition sequence-0 to offset 0.
Jul 10, 2019 2:52:01 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState maybeSeekUnvalidated
INFO: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=carthusian-consumer] Resetting offset for partition sequence-1 to offset 0.
    Loaded 9804 records from [sequence-0] partitions
    Loaded 9804 records from [sequence-1] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-0] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-1] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-0] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-1] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-0] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-1] partitions
    Loaded 9799 records from [sequence-0] partitions
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved by placing the following (simple) log4j.properties under src/main/resources and running the app straight from console (rather than from the IDE). Fetching messages are now shown.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

At the moment I do not know which class is generating the messages I am looking for, hence the DEBUG setting on the rootLogger.